# Detect "Close" button in local notification

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am programming an app where the user sets a kind of daily alarm where the application shows certain information every day at the same time. I'm try to make this feature with local notifications. My problem is when the user press the close button of the local notification received, because there is no way to detect this event. I have been searching and seems no solution. I just post this question to be sure there is no solution about the "Close" event.

Thank you

Comment: what u want to do for that close event.? if user taps close, as ur notification is fired, & this notification will not be in ur app, scheduled notifications list, u can get something from here..?

Comment: if the user press "Close" on the LNotification, I want to re-schedule another LNotification at the same time the user had set on the picker time. I can do that if the user press the action, but I don't know how to do it if the user press "Close" because the app doesn't get the event.

Comment: i dont think its possible, as app is not active, we cant track the alert.

Comment: Painful, but this is it. I'll find another way to re-schedule later LN. Thank you anyway vishy !

Answer (score 0):

did you try do add a repeating notification?

check this property: notif.repeatInterval

you can add a repeating notification, that fires every hour or day or ...